# gcloud cant deploy nodejs app

Tags: node.js, deployment, gcloud

I am trying the free trial of gcloud using nodejs, I am gettng an error while deployment

```
Updating module [default]...failed.
ERROR: (gcloud.preview.app.deploy) Server responded with code [400]:
Bad Request Unexpected HTTP status 400.
The version field in the app.yaml file must match the version provided as a GET parameter.
```

I checked everything is running fine and configured well.

Note that I have another application that's already running over gcloud.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for reporting this–it looks like a bug. To confirm, you don't have a `version` field in your `app.yaml`, right? You can work around this by downgrading to a version like `0.9.84`: `gcloud components update --version=0.9.84` (this version is known-good; later versions before 0.9.88 might still work).

Comment: Yes, I don't, Gcloud nodejs tutorial offers the version parameters only using the terminal to pass it as a parameter !!

Thanks for your help

Comment: working with 0.9.84 gives me this error 

 Updating module [default]...failed.
ERROR: (gcloud.preview.app.deploy) Server responded with code [500]:
  Internal Server Error.
  
Server Error (500)
A server error has occurred.

Comment: Odd. Did you set `use_appengine_api` to `false`? If so, can you try again with `gcloud config set app/use_appengine_api true` (at either version).

Comment: Thanks, setting     use_appengine_api true 
solved it

Comment: @ZacharyNewman, I have the above issue with use_appengine_api=false too (is this a bug that will be fixed? Seems to occur with both 0.9.84 and 0.9.88). Unfortunately the default of use_appengine_api=true gives me other errors when attempting to deploy, which is why I was fiddling with other use_appengine_api=false (app_id dancedeets-hrd with Error Response: [13] Giving up due to transient errors. Please try again. Version: 20151201t145817.388962977619500789)

Comment: @MikeLambert please file a bug [here](https://b.corp.google.com/u/0/issues/new) about the issues you're having with `user_appengine_api=true`. There appears to be some issue with the backend powering non-App Engine API deployments; it's hard to say if/when it will be fixed because we're trying very hard to move over to the App Engine API. App Engine API issues should be fixed promptly.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @ZacharyNewman . But sorry, I left Google earlier this year, so no more Buganizer for me...stackoverflow is all I really get now. ;)

However, I was able to revert changes until I found something that worked. Looks like when I changed my app.yaml's "vm_settings:"'s "vm_runtime:" from "python27" to "custom", it triggered the so-called "transient errors" with use_appengine_api=true. (I had changed it because an updated gcloud-sdk told me I could no longer use a "runtime: python27", and I was overeager in which runtime fields I changed to be "custom")

Comment: Oh, I'm so sorry--that was the wrong URL. I meant here: <https://code.google.com/p/google-cloud-sdk/issues/list> (which you should have access to). But you've given mean enough detail that I can go ahead and file it on your behalf. Thanks!

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/google-cloud-sdk/issues/detail?id=410 is tracking the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for @zachary-newman

setting

```
use_appengine_api true
```

solved it